# General error in JDBC(updating database)

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

```
private void sUpdateBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String query = "UPDATE Student SET lastname = ?, firstname = ?, course = ?, yearlvl = ?, username = ?, password = ?";
        dbConn = DbConnection.dbConnect();
        prepState = dbConn.prepareStatement(query);
        prepState.setString(1, sLnTf.getText());
        prepState.setString(2, sFnTf.getText());
        prepState.setString(3, courseTf.getText());
        prepState.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(yearLvlTf.getText()));
        prepState.setString(5, sUserTf.getText());
        prepState.setString(6, sPassTf.getText());
        prepState.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){
        appendEvent(sdf.format(new Date()) + " Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Method for connecting to the database:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DbConnection {
    Connection dbConn = null;

    public static Connection dbConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=H:/Integ Ongoing Project/_Midterm Project/Server/src/database/Database.accdb");
            return dbConn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NoQuestionFoundException.

Comment: I think the answer is 7

Comment: It's actually 7 * 6 = 42.

Comment: You omitted ***alot*** of information from your question, like the code you are using to execute the query, the error stacktrace, and what steps you have have already tried to solve the problem. Also note that you have a *huge* bug in your update query - you should be pretty grateful its doesn't actually run.

Comment: Yikes, that wouldnt be ideal

Comment: sori sir for that, this was my first time and i only have little knowledge about JDBC because this is my first project in school.
the code is executed when ever the update button is clicked
the first thing i did was to change the prepState.setString(4, yearLvl.getText() to prepState.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(yearLvl.getText()) because the data type of yearLvl in my database is a number

sir can you point out exactly the huge bug that you saw in my code please for me to learn more about this bugs.

Answer (score 1):

*Password* is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P).  If you must keep that as your field name, enclose it in brackets in your query to reduce the likelihood of confusing the database engine.

```sql
UPDATE Student
SET
    lastname = ?,
    firstname = ?,
    course = ?,
    yearlvl = ?,
    username = ?,
    [password] = ?
WHERE student_id = ?
```

Note I included a `WHERE` clause, as Stephen suggested, because it seems unlikely you would want those same field values applied to *every* row in the `Student` table.  I used `student_id` as a placeholder name for the table's primary key ... the field which uniquely identifies each row.  My intention is that you revise the `WHERE` clause to reference the primary key for the student whose record you want to alter.

If you're actually trying to add a new record, instead of update an existing record (or records), use an `INSERT` statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO Student (
    lastname,
    firstname,
    course,
    yearlvl,
    username,
    [password]
    )
VALUES (
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?,
    ?
    )
```

And if you have autonumber as the data type of your primary key, the db engine will manage it for you.

Comment: thank you very much sir I tried the suggestions that you have gave me and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your SQL statement is missing a WHERE clause.  (I know that WHERE is optional in some dialects of SQL ... but a missing WHERE makes no sense to me here.)

The reason I think this is wrong is that even if the SQL dialect allows this, it is not clear *which* row of the table you are "setting".  Even if the SQL engine can figure it out, a WHERE clause makes it a lot clearer.  (And the fact that it "works" in the other case, doesn't mean that it is necessarily correct.)

Another thing that is potentially the cause of the problem is that "password" is a reserved word in some SQL dialects.  Change the column name, or escape it.

---

Finally, the actual SQL error message *should* be in the exception stacktrace, or failing that in the log files.  Those should be the *first* places to look if you are trying to find a problem in your database code.  Look for the **evidence** ... rather than hoping someone else guess the right answer for you.

Comment: i have tried putting where clause in my query but it still doesn't work at all

my second query which updates the records of the faculty is working properly, they have the same syntax with the updating of students